# Regular expression to replace <br style="..."> by <br style="..."/>

Tags: html, regex

I need a regular expression to help me close the `<br>` tag to comply with the `xhtml` standard. In my html `br` does not always comes `empty`, so the `regex` has to account for it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: With which program will you like to do the replacements?

Answer (score 1):

Look for this pattern

```
(\<br[^\>]*)(\/)?(\>)
```

And replace with this

```
$1/$3
```

Based on the engine you may need to use `\1/\2` instead of `$1/$3` in the replacement string.

Comment: The space was considered just in case for malformed html tags. And thanks for the empty `<br>` point.

Answer (score 0):

The regex might also look a bit simpler:

replace

```
/<br.*?>/i
```

with

```
<br\/>
```